# Why C++ Allocator concept has construct and destroy functionality?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I think the only task of Allocator is allocating and deallocating memories, why don't I just use constructor and destructor of some type to initialize and finalize?
If I never implement construct and destroy method, std::allocator_traits will still use constructor and destructor of T to do the work, I know std::allocator just works this way (C++17), why not all Allocator work like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, the main use case of `construct` and `destroy` that I'm aware of, is to allow making an allocator aware containers hierarchical: that is, it will automatically use the same allocator for any nested objects. This is accomplished via `scoped_allocator_adaptor`, which is a special allocator that "adapts" an existing allocator, and it does define `construct` so that it passes down the allocator. This is useful for the common case where you have, say, a `vector<string>` and you want all of the internal strings to use the same allocator as the vector. This can only be accomplished if the allocator controls construction, and it can pass itself as an extra argument to anything it's asked to construct.

I'd read further about it here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor.

In theory you could also use this for instrumentation; it might be useful in non production builds, but it's a really marginal use case (IMHO). Users of the allocator almost always call `allocate` and then `construct`, so there's limited value in instrumenting `construct` separately.

Edit: I should say, that's the main use case for `construct`. `destroy` is then there just for symmetry.